# Find inverse $f^{-1}$ of a function $f(x,y)=(x-y,x-10y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, inverse

I know how to find inverse function if the given function is in the explicit form. Could someone show on this example how to find $f^{-1}$?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Hint: Write $f(x) = Ax$ with $A = (1,-1 ; 1,-10)$ and find the inverse of the matrix $A$ (e.g. via Gauss algorithm)!

Comment: @ Zardo I got $A^{-1}=(\frac{10}{9}, \frac{1}{9}; \frac{-1}{9}, \frac{-1}{9})$. Is this correct and is $A^{-1}=f^{-1}$? Is it possible to express $f^{-1}$ in explicit form?

Comment: This looks correct. Technically $f^{-1}$ is the mapping with $f^{-1}(x)= A^{-1}x$ and not $A^{-1}$ itself. You can write out $f^{-1}$ explicitely by using the definition of matrix multiplication and get what Siminore got below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x-y=u$ and $x-10y=v$, then $9y=u-v$. Hence $y=(u-v)/9$. Finally, $x=y+u=(u-v)/9+u$. Therefore
$$
f^{-1} \colon (u,v) \mapsto (u+(u-v)/9,(u-v)/9).
$$